# Не работает меню в python django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, menu

Поставил по инструкции меню [django-menu](https://github.com/rossp/django-menu)

Добавил в админке пункты меню и прописал в шаблон html:

```
<ul>
    {% load menubuilder %}{% menu headernavigation %}
    {% for item in menuitems %}<li><a href="{{ item.url }}" title="{{ item.title|escape }}"{% if item.current %} class='current'{% endif %}>{{ item.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Меню не выводится, ошибки не показывает, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам, кому может поможет
при выводе в html, надо указывать название вашего меню вместо headernavigation